# Ignore e2e folder when running npm test

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, jestjs, detox

I am using detox as the end-2-end tester for my react-native app but I don't want whats in the e2e folder to be included when I run npm test. I am currently using jest for the npm test.

This is what i have in my package.json:

```
 "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "node_modules/(?!(react-native|static-container|expo|@expo|react-navigation))"
        ]
      },
```

The e2e folder is located in my root directory and my test files are in my **tests** folder in the root directory also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get around this problem when I run my jest tests I use the [testMatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string) property and set it in the `package.json` this means that it will only match the tests that are in the folders that I have specified.

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "testMatch": [
  "<rootDir>/__tests__/**/*.test.js?(x)",
  "<rootDir>/app/**/*.test.js"
  ]
},
```

Alternatively you can use to ignore specific paths.

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/e2e"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Sorry I thought I had it pressed. Thanks again